# Using "dynamic" layout pages in MVC3

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I've got a question about layout pages in MVC3:

Is it possible to use a server-generated (e.g. loaded from a database) layout pages like:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Handler.ashx?layout=xyz";
}
```

Will code inside the layout like `@RenderBody()` work?

If anyone of you already tried something like this, I would be happy to hear about your experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [create a custom view engine](http://coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/) and serve those views from wherever you want (including a database).

Comment: Which means, that it isn't possible just to supply a link which generates a layout like in my example given above?

Comment: @Dänu, of course that this isn't possible. You need a custom view engine, implement the `IView` interface in order to serve views from other non standard locations such as a database.